# Multiple Inline If-Else with Conditional Operator

Tags: reactjs, conditional-operator, conditional-rendering

Can you give me a hand with this expression . Basically what i am trying to say is
If `props.row.registered` is `true` set disabled to be `true` or if is `props.row.registered` is `undefined` set it to false.

```
<Button
     disabled={!props.row.registered ? true : !props.row.registered === undefined ? false : true}
    ...
    />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ternary operator is basically doing this:

```
if(props.row.registered === true) {
  return true;
else {
  return false;
}
```

which can be simplified to:

```
return props.row.registered;
```

So for your conditions it would be:

```
props.row.registered || props.row.registered !== undefined
```

(based on your statement since your code it's setting disabled to `true` if `props.row.registered` is `false`, which is the opposite of your statement)

Comment: `!props.row.registered === undefined` seems fishy :) did you want to write `&& props.row.registered !== undefined`? In general, `undefined` is `falsy` though.

Comment: basically the idea is when i get a boolean value from `props.row.registered` to determinate the disabled , but when i dont have acess to this value in my case `undefined` to return the button to be `disabled=false`

Comment: `disabled={!props.row.registered && props.row.registered !== undefined}` this have done the job thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

Your boolean can have 4 values: `false`, `true`, `undefined` and `null`.

```
disabled={props.row.registered}
```

should be enough for your use case because `undefined` and `null` are both falsy.

Comment: yeah but i want when i have a `undefined` value the disabled to be setted to false. In my case when i write `disabled={!props.row.registered}` is working fine but when i switch to the next page for some reason the rest of the buttons when they dont have this `registered` boolean value or value of undefined they are also disabled .

Comment: @PandaMastr Then your error is probably somewhere else. `undefined` won't make your  button disabled. Note there is no `!` in mine since you said that you want `registered === true` to make the button disabled.